# Connecting Facebook page and Facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, botframework

Goal : Connecting an application with existing Facebook page.
Why ? I want to allow user to use their page as bot. Facebook app is a bot.

Reason : User wants a bot for Facebook page but does not allow admin permissions.

What I've tried : 
Get all users pages :

```
 if ( typeof (response.authResponse) !== 'undefined')
            {
                token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "api/FB/GetCode?token=" + token,
                }).done(function (data) {

                    var mySelect = $('.dropdown');
                    mySelect.empty();
                    $.each(data.accounts.data, function (val, text) {
                        mySelect.append(
                            $('<option></option>').val(text.access_token).html(text.name)
                        );
                    });
                    mySelect.show();
                    $('.connectWithBot').show();
                });
            } else {
                //do the login logic
            }
```

Then when user has chosen page :

```
 FB.api(
        'pageId/subscribed_apps?access_token=' + 
$('.dropdown').find(":selected").val(),
        'post',
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response && !response.error) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

So when one page instance is connected with one application, this not gonna work anymore. Its okey that way.

Is it possible to get this work ? Or maybe you guys have a better idea ?

Comment: _“So when one page instance is connected with one application, this not gonna work anymore”_ – no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: One application (bot configured) for one Facebook page. Reason : User wants a bot for Facebook page but does not allow admin permissions.

Comment: If the user wants to install your bot on their page, then of course that requires that they grant admin access to the page … but that still doesn’t properly explain what you meant by that statement. If you can install it on one page, you can install it on multiple pages, too - what is your exact problem with that?